# can not get the selected words in uiwebview

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, selected, words

i want to get the selected words in UIWebView.but sometimes i couldn't get that.this is my code.

I use javascript to get the selected words.(getSelectedword.js)

```
var selectedText = "";
function getTextSelection() {
   var text = window.getSelection();
   selectedText = text.anchorNode.textContent.substr(text.anchorOffset, text.focusOffset - text.anchorOffset);

 }
```

and then

```
-(void)showHeightlight
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"getSelectedword" ofType:@"js"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getTextSelection()"];
NSString *result  = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"selectedText"];
NSLog(@"selected: %@", result);
```

}

if i selected the words and change the scope,I couldn't get the selected words.

Answer (score 1):

I change my core like that.it's ok.

getSelectedword.js

```
function getTextSelection() {
var text = window.getSelection();
return text.toString();
}
```

and then

```
-(void)showHeightlight
{
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"getSelectedword" ofType:@"js"];
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
 NSString *result  = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getTextSelection()"];
 NSLog(@"selected: %@", result);
}
```